# Wondering why my XML URL Feed data is not displaying to HTML on the front-end. If I host the static XML in my directory, it works

Tags: javascript, html, xml, twitter-bootstrap, rss

Wondering why my XML URL Feed data is not displaying to HTML on the front-end. If I host the static XML in my directory, it works. However, when using a live feed from https://www.prlog.org/news/us/ind/sports/rss.xml, it does not work???

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Test XML Feed</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  </head>
  <body>
        <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
            <div class="container">
                <h1 class="display-8">Testing XML Feed</h1>
                <hr class="my-2">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div id="title"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div id="description"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
             </div>
         </div>
      
      <script>
        //Display it
        function displayFEED(i) {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    myFunction(this, i);
                }
            };
            //Call XML Feed with Live URL
            xmlhttp.open("GET", 'https://www.prlog.org/news/us/ind/sports/rss.xml', true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
        displayFEED(1);


        // Call tag names from XML and match ID's
        function myFunction(xml, i) {
            var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML; 
            x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("channel");
            document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = x[i].getElementsByTagName("description")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
         
        }
        </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Same origin policy? What does the browser error or network console (F12) show related to the failure? Probably warnings or errors that the cross-origin request from your domain or localhost to `www.prlog.org` is not allowed unless that site sets CORS headers.

Comment: @MartinHonnen little confused on your response. Are you able to explain? Thank you!

Comment: Well,, read up on the same origin policy and CORS on MDN or Wikipedia or your favourite client-side JS book. Or fire up the developer console of your browser with F12 and see what it shows you.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thank you! In the console, I am getting the following: "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.prlog.org/news/us/ind/sports/rss.xml' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

I understand I need to add this "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" after reading up. However, I am not sure where to add it in.

Comment: It is not you who needs to set this, rather whoever runs the remote site you are trying to access needs to allow different origin access by setting an appropriate header. It is kind of odd that in the world of browser you can probably pull and integrate images with e.g. `img src` or JavaScript or JSON data or even complete HTML documents with e.g. `iframe` from anyone's server while XML/XSLT resources fall under the same origin policy. But it has been that way for lots of years. So either get the remote site to set up the header to allow access or set up a server-side proxy.

Answer (score 0):

If the server cooperates, your code using `XMLHttpRequest` can pull the remote resource; for the sample subdomain below I have configured the header and that way the code run here on stackoverflow.com can access the file fine:

```js
const uri = 'https://cors-resources.liberty-development.net/sample1.xml';

const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', uri);
req.onload = function(e) {
  console.log(req.responseXML);
};
req.send();
```

But if the server does not cooperate you can't do anything but set up some kind of proxy service on your own site and have it pull the remote URIs with server-side code on your own site while client-side JavaScript simply connects to your own site.

Comment: Thank you!

Makes sense. Is it possible to also display XML Attributes? With the below, what if I wanted to display the score and the attribute of the team name? 

Example: 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soccer>
 <Home-Team HomeTeamName="Eagles">1</Home-Team>
 <Away-Team AwayTeamName="Dogs">2</Away-Team>
</soccer>

Comment: @Chris7, the DOM core programming is shared between HTML and XML so if you know to use e.g. `getAttribute`. But it seems you need to start with a general introduction like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction, perhaps.

Comment: Thank you @martinhonnen. I will look into this!